# Parsing .RTF file into a C# RichTextBox erases the Check Boxes

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox, rtf

I'm currently trying to parse an RTF file into C# and a lot of information online points to using a Windows.Form RichTextBox to do so. After loading the file and inspecting the RichTextBox.Text everything has been captured correctly except for Check Boxes that are used within the document. The information from these check boxes are vital to what I am trying to perform within my program. Has anyone come across this before?

```
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
rtb.LoadFile(fileRTF);
Console.WriteLine(rtb.Text);
```

[Original document VS console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdekw.png)

Many thanks!

- I've attempted removing all protection from the document
- The checkboxes appear in Word, and Notepad++ upon inspection. But they do not appear within Wordpad
- Copying the checkboxes and posting them into another document results in a binary output of 0/1 based on checked or not
- i've tried using the NRTFTree library with no success

Comment: Can you provide the minimal RTF source that recreates what is in the screenshot and then based of that, what the expected outcome is? Is the issue that not all content appears on the console? Or is the issue that the RichtextBox control doesn't show everything? What code did you try with the NRTFTree library?

Comment: `[RichTextBox].Text` doesn't include any rendering of graphic glyphs. Just text. Since Wordpad doesn't show the checkboxes, even if you showed the RichTextBox Control somewhere, you most probably wouldn't see them anyway: the two use the same version of the underlying library (assuming you're using at least .NET Framework 4.7.1). Word uses a different one

Answer (score 0):

The Console output is plain text, so it can not display any rich display.